# How to bundle.min.css only in a specific page(in my case contact.php)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to load `bundle.min.css` only in `contact.php`. Is there any solution so it effect only `contact.php` with other css. And i wanna exclude `bundle.min.css` from other pages.

```
<?php
function tex_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'googleapi', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-s', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icon-fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'essential-regular-fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icon-fonts/essential-regular-fonts/essential-icons.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/reset.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/magnific-popup.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'common-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/common.css', ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myncss-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/myncss.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bundle-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bundle.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'animate-css',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css',array(),'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/portfolio.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tex_enqueue');

?>
```

Comment: Yes, You can call just direct to contact.php page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom css to a page template in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249774/add-custom-css-to-a-page-template-in-wordpress)

Comment: please pass me the format to include it in contact page also mention the section

Comment: I have no idea what you just asked. Did you check the suggested duplicate? It does what you ask.

Comment: no it dint work for me . i want all the above css in contact.php(slug-contact.php) but i just wanna exclude bundle.min.css in all other pages but include only in contact.php(slug-contact.php)

Comment: _"it dint work for me"_ - Then you didn't implement it correctly. You only add the `bundle.min.css` into the `if`-statement. All other styles should be outside of the `if`. Then all (except `bundle.min.css`) will be loaded on all pages.

Comment: i wanted to apply bundle.min.css to entire pae of contact but footer style is changing how can i apply to contact page except footer.is there any way?if so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your css on specific page by using **is_page('your_page_id')** condition tag.

Create page template for your contact.php, See this link : [Click Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)

Use the below code in your current active theme **functions.php** file.

```
function tex_enqueue() {
      if(is_page('your-contact-page-id')){
         wp_enqueue_style( 'bundle-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bundle.min.css' );
      }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tex_enqueue');
```

For more help see this link : [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: if ( is_page('contact.php') ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bundle-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bundle.min.css' );
       }     i have added this but bundle.min.css is not loading in contact.php(slug-contact.php)

Comment: it was my mistake i added if ( is_page('contact.php') ) where i suppose to add if ( is_page('contact') )

Comment: i wanted to apply bundle.min.css to entire pae of contact but footer style is changing how can i  apply to contact page except footer.is there any way?if so please help me

Comment: If its help you then mark as solution, so it can help to other developer also.

Comment: js works with the whole documents . Means for div one we did'nt need to add other js and for div 2 we add second js. Its impossible, js file work with the whole documents and dom. So with single js file we can handle all the dom of the current documents. If your footer not working then it may cause other issue.